# Dynamically add/remove a class a div depending on a boolean attribute

Tags: jquery, gallery, src

I'm trying to make an image src (**.zoomImg** ***src***) get its "value" from the value of another img attribute (.**image-zoom** ***data-zoom***) which parent (.**main-slider** .**slick-slide**) changes whenever its attribute ('***aria-hidden***') shifts to (="**false**").

**HTML**:

```html
<div class="main-slider slick-slider">
    <div class="slick-slide activated" aria-hidden="false">
        <span>
            <img class ="image-zoom" src="s/files/firstpicture_480x480.jpeg" data-zoom="s/files/firstpicture_1024x1024.jpeg">
            <img class="zoomImg" src="s/files/firstpicture_1024x1024.jpeg">
        </span>
    </div>  
    <div class="slick-slide" aria-hidden="true">
        <img class ="image-zoom" src="s/files/secondpicture_480x480.jpeg" data-zoom="s/files/secondpicture_1024x1024.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="slick-slide" aria-hidden="true">
        <img class ="image-zoom" src="s/files/thirdpicture_480x480.jpeg" data-zoom="s/files/thirdpicture_1024x1024.jpeg">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="navigation-slider slick-slider">
    <div class="slick-slide" aria-hidden="false">
        <img class ="image-zoom" src="s/files/firstpicture_240x240.jpeg"
    </div>  
     <div class="slick-slide" aria-hidden="false">
        <img class ="image-zoom" src="s/files/secondpicture_240x240.jpeg">
    </div>
     <div class="slick-slide" aria-hidden="false">
        <img class ="image-zoom" src="s/files/thirdpicture_240x240.jpeg">
    </div>
</div>
```

So far I managed to make the initial part work thanks to a class (".**activated**") that is added when the ('***aria-hidden***') attribute of the **main slider image div** is set to (="**false**"), but as soon as the slide changes, the (**aria-hidden="false"**) switches to the new slide parent and everything falls apart.

**JQUERY**:

```js
$('.main-slider .slick-slide').filter('[aria-hidden="false"]').addClass('activated');

$(document).ready(function () { //ZOOMSCRIPT
    $(".activated .image-zoom")
    .wrap('<span style="display:inline-block"></span>')
    .css("display", "block")
    .parent()
    .zoom({
    url: $(this).find("img").attr("data-zoom"),
    });
});
```

Could you please help me figuring out how to remove this class whenever **aria-hidden="true"** and to automatically reassign it to the new image's parent where **aria-hidden="false"**?

Comment: Welcome ! Are you sure it's the best approach to do it ? I mean did you check slick slider available events ? Can you use StackOverflow snippets or JsFiddle, Codepen.. ? That would help us visualize the transition you are mentioning and hopefully give you the best solution.

Comment: I did, on slick's doc they mention "beforeChange" and "afterChange", I tried to initialize the zoom, then on "afterChange"destroy it before re-initializing it, with no success. Can you check the answer below and tell me what you think ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I tried this code it appears to be a better approach but I can't make it work ('slider-for' is the name of the container):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  
     function initZoom() { 
        $('.image-zoom')
        .wrap('<span style="display:inline-block"></span>')
        .css('display', 'block')
        .parent()
        .zoom({
            url: $(this).find("img").attr("data-zoom")
        });
     }
  
         $('.slider-for').on('afterChange', function() {
          $(".image-zoom").trigger("zoom.destroy");
          alert('slide change');
          initZoom();
        });  
  
  
});
```

Comment: The idea is clear... but can you share a snippet.. with your css styles ? There is a snippet editor in Stackoverflow you better get used to it :)